# recommended software that monitors the usage of a website?

Tags: monitoring

I have a website in production and want to monitor not just the number of visitors but the distribution percentage of its possible actions, which of them are the most required and in what frequency

which software would you recommend to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Remote/online or hosted on your website? Define 'possible actions' because you will probably have to design the relation between *action* and *page visits*, regardless of which software you use. And are you unfamiliair with [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)? See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: by actions I mean.. search by a word, open different popups to fill forms and save/update different kind of data.. there are pages in the website that contains all of these posible actions through ajax so I can't do an analysis through a page url request

I can do this type of usage analysis by logging each action but I want some kind of software to remotely monitor that online. I'm unfamiliar with Google Analytics and any kind of this type of software.. can I use it to get the distribution percentage of the actions?

Comment: No Google Analytics can't do that if I remember correctly. You obviously need something much more granular than page visits. Please [edit] your comment answer into your text. The more complete your question the larger the chances you get help. Did you read that link?